# How to estimate the odds ratio with CI for X in a logistic regression containing the square of X using R?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, logistic-regression

I am trying to calculate odds ratios in R for variables with not only linear but also with quadratic terms in logistic regression. Let's say there is X and X^2 in the model. I know how to get the odds ratio (for a unit change of X) when X takes a specific value, but I don't know how to calculate confidence interval for this estimate. I found this reference how it's done in SAS: http://support.sas.com/kb/35/189.html , but I would like to do it in R. Any suggestions?

@BenBolker
Here is an example:

```
mydata <-read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
mydata <- transform(mydata, gpaSquared=gpa^2,greSquared=gre^2)
model <- glm(admit ~ gpa + gpaSquared  + gre , family = binomial(logit), data = mydata)
```

In this example the odds ratio for gpa depends on the actual value of gpa (e.g. the effect of a unit change in gpa if gpa=4). I can calculate the log odds for gpa=5 and gpa=4 and get the odds ratio from those, but I don't know how to get CI for the OR. (please ignore that in the example the squared term is not stat. significant...)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics. This should be migrated to crossvalidated.com.

Comment: It's funny, I got the same comment on crossvalidated.com, that's why I came here :)

Comment: can you give a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

```
m <- glm(x~X1^2+X2,data,family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(m)
confint(m) # 95% CI for the coefficients using profiled log-likelihood
confint.default(m) ## CIs using standard errors
exp(coef(m)) # exponentiated coefficients
exp(confint(m)) # 95% CI for exponentiated coefficients
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but it's not exactly my case. I have sg like:

m <- glm(x~ X1+X1^2+X2,data,family=binomial(link="logit"))

which means OR will depend on the value of X1.